# how can I disable the options menu from action bar(not the menu items)

Tags: android-actionbar

I have a activity which is hosting 3 fragments. A,B,C. For the hosting activity and Fragment A, it should show the options menu, so I am inflating it in fragment A.

Now For fragment B and C I just want to display the action bar(having title and back arrow), and disable the complete options menu dropdown(the 3 dots in the right corner). 
I tried using setHasMenuOptions(false) in fragments B and C but its not working.

Is there any option to hide the three dots with dropdown in other two fragments.

My activity has the following code to perform the back navigation. Everything is working fine accept hiding the complete menu in the two fragments B and C.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
               super.onBackPressed();
               return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onPrepareOptionsMenu in yor fragment class and do menu.clear();
Also do setHasMenuOptions(true);

```
 public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.clear();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I figured out .visible(false), but for every menuitem I was supposed to write and it was taking lot more lines.